# Spring Boot & JAAS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jaas

I have an existing legacy SOAP webservice that runs on Tomcat and uses JAAS(Java authentication & authorization service) for user authentication. I would like to convert this to a SOAP service which runs on Spring boot. I also want to continue with the JAAS configuration for security. How can I integrate JAAS with Spring boot?

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: are you able to configure JAAS with Spring Boot?.. I have a similar requirement but not able to do so